# Cannot implicitly convert type bool to string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a check name method to see if the user exist in the database. I created a Check() function/Method in a class called SqlFunctions2.But I have an error in my code and I can't seem to fix. Any help would be appreciate it. Thanks :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Contact_Form
{
   public class SqlFunctions2
    {
       static private SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("My string connection here");

       public static string Check(string name)
       { 


           try
           {
               conn.Open();
               int Exist;
               /*Check to see if the username is in the database.*/
               SqlCommand exist_cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from tbl_contact_form where name=@name", conn);
               exist_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
               Exist = (int)exist_cmd.ExecuteScalar();


               if (Exist == 1)
               {

                   SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                   SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_contact_form where name=@name", conn);
                   myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                   myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                   while (myReader.Read())
                   {
                       string result_name = myReader["name"].ToString();
                       string result_amount = myReader["amount_borrowed"].ToString();

                       return true; /* error in this line of code...
                                   Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'*/
                   }
               }
               else if(Exist == 0)
               {
                    return false;
                    MessageBox.Show("No such user.");
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
           }
           finally
           {
           conn.Close();
           }

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Your `Check` method return type is `string` but you try to return `true` which is `bool` and there is no implicit conversation between them. Either change your return type of your method or return something iin your method that matches with your return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is declared to return a `string`

```
 public static string Check(string name)
               ^ Here
```

And you try to return a `boolean` value (true or false).
You can either return a string value or change the function to return a boolean value instead.

---

Although, your code should not compile but rather give you an error which looks something like:

> Error 'Contact_Form.SqlFunctions2.Check(string)': not all code paths return a value

Cause your function do not seem to return any value in case there is an exception in the `try` clause.

---

Also note, in this part:

```
else if(Exist == 0)
{
    return false;
    MessageBox.Show("No such user.");
}
```

You return (exits the function) before showing the Message box.
That is, the message box will never be shown in case the user does not exist.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but you again you were right on the other error I'm getting... Error 'Contact_Form.SqlFunctions2.Check(string)': not all code paths return a value. Why am I seeing this error now?

Comment: A function have to return a value at each exit point, you don't (if it enters the `catch` it wont return anything). Also, feel free to mark the answer as correct if it gave you what you required to fix your original issue.

Comment: Oh, I see, and yeah I definitely changed my method to bool and the return to false after the message box. But now I'm facing this not all code  paths return a value... So do you think the try catch block is what is making this error appear?

Comment: Well yes, you do not return anything if the code enters the catch, you need to return something at the end of a function, always (exception when a function returns void, where you don't have to type out the return).

Comment: Thanks, I added the return at the end of the functions and it cleared out my error. :)

Answer (score 1):

The method check is of the type String and since you are returning a bool, you must change the method Check to:

```
public static bool Check(string name)
```

As you can see it has a type of bool now, and can now accept bool return statements.
Either that, or if you are wanting it to return a string saying true or false, you must use `return "true";` or `return "false";` so that the system can properly identify its type.